Naming some inverted chords
I'm trying to break down an orchestral score (in C-minor) and describe the horn part, but I'm having troubles describing these chords (the second image is identical, but I mapped horns 2-4 onto the bass clef in case it's easier for some people).  I've put it all in C, so no transposition is needed.


The second chord is easier.  If I look at the clarinets, F,A,C is an F-major triad.  Those notes are reflected in the Horn section, but there is some inversion happening, and a dominant 7th (Eb) is at the bottom.  With the inversions and the low 7, would you still call that an F7, or is there a better way to describe it?  Maybe F/Eb?
The first chord is more difficult.  If I look at the clarinets again, it looks like an Ab-minor triad with the minor 3rd (Cb) notated as B, and an inversion with the 5th at the bottom.  Mapping that onto the horns, I see the same inverted minor-triad below the staff (or in the bass staff), but with a dominant 7th on top.

I see D at the bottom of both the clarinet and horn parts, not E flat like you imply.

Hm, you're right.  D is not the 5th of an Abm7.  It's a tri-tone.  I really don't know what that chord is.  Maybe a half-diminished Am7b5 with some inversions?

Adding a reference to the orchestral work and the measure number would be nice.

Title, composer, and measure numbers? The context can affect the answer.

Richard Wagner, Gotterdammerung, Start of act 3, scene 3 (page 534/615).  Sorry, no measure numbers or rehearsal marks in this score.

Uh oh, Wagner started going into non-functional harmony (or at least went for only "tonic" and "non-tonic" for music).

The 2nd chord contains E♭, F, A and C, so is fair and square F dominant 7. In any order at all, those four notes only constitute F7. However, in that 3rd inversion (E♭ at the bottom makes it that, then to be more specific, it could be F/E♭, or if you like F7/E♭.
1st is more tricky! It sounds like Bm6, which has B, D, F♯ and G♯ in it. Written as you did, the flats have masked the latter two notes - calling them by their other (enharmonic) names.
But, with a D note under, it could be Bm6 in 1st inversion, otherwise known as Bm6/D. A nice chromatic move.

Might be a little early to accept this answer! Half the world hasn't woken up yet, others may be forthcoming!

I think it's a pretty good answer.  If someone else has a better answer then maybe I'll change it, but I appreciate the response!

@Stewart I think it's better to wait before you accept an answer than to unaccept, for two reasons: One, it feels very disappointing to have one's answer accepted and then unaccepted. And second, a question without an accepted answer is inviting more answers. A question with an answer accepted signalises "problem resolved, no need to bother".
